# mysql run multiple selects on the same table at the same time

Tags: mysql

We have 25 queries, which are simple select statements, that we need to run concurrently on the same table, to test load.

How do I run multiple select statements at the exact same time?
I have tried a bash script, but it runs the selects in order, and not at the same time

Comment: *we need to run concurrently on the same table, to test load* You MUST execute them using different connections to MySQL server. 25 queries - 25 connections. *I have tried a bash script* One bash session - one connection. Start 25 separate sessions (for example from one "main" session).

Comment: Show us the bash script.

Comment: @Akina, thank you, will try a few sessions at the same time

Comment: If your goal is to tesl load without network transfer influence use queries with a minimal output (for example, to test load of some SELECT use it as a subquery with SELECT COUNT(some_fileld) in outer query).

Comment: You might find [this](https://www.hammerdb.com/) of interest?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The workload needs to open sessions in parallel, instead of executing all queries serially from one bash script.

There is a MySQL tool aimed at just this, please see `mysqlslap`.

https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/mysqlslap.html

Answer (score 0):

At some point, any query will grab a Mutex that prevents other queries from proceeding.  That is, it is *impossible* to run queries at *exactly* the same time.

What you can do (and mysqlslap and other tools do) is to keep pumping queries into the system, not quite in parallel, but "continuously".  From that you can get "tps" or "qps".

Another thing to be cautious about is the number of connections that are feeding queries into mysql.  In the old days, 4-8 would saturate the system, tps would stall or decline and latency would go through the roof.  Current versions probably get past 64 connections before such happens.

When there are a hundred queries running at the same time, the contention for resources is so high that none of the connections is getting much done.  It becomes a tradeoff between concurrency and latency.

When latency is too high, users complain that the system is "hung", and the novice DBA decides that the only cure is to reboot.